# Is there any way for a non-US person to get a US-based bank account?

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, brokerage

I live in the EU. After signing up with various brokers across the pond, I noticed that some have decent low-cost deposit/ withdrawal fees, while others' are abnormally high.

For instance, Interactive Brokers charges nothing for SEPA deposits and the first withdrawal is free of charge, but TastyWorks requires you to deposit via CurrencyFair, which takes a ~$20 cut, and then international wire withdrawals are $25 a piece. Which is insane.

I would love to have access to multiple brokerage services, but this requires me to have a US-based bank account to reduce the deposits/ withdrawal fees to 0 (by using the ACH payment network).

Is there any way an EU resident could obtain this, assuming that they have no American family member?

Comment: Note that the "already answered" thread you've been referenced to is 10 years old, and some of that advice is out of date. If you can find a bank which operates in both your country and in the US, you might find it possible that way. There have been significant changes in recent years around proof of identity (anti money laundering), and in my experience it is more difficult to open international accounts, especially if not residing in the country. Maybe check Transferwise. Would be nice if the mods considered re-opening your question to allow some more up to date answers.

Comment: Oh, thanks Peter. I actually haven't looked at the dates on the previous thread. Indeed it'd be great if the question was reopened.

Comment: You could try re-asking your question, but specifically mention that you've already found posts like the one above (and link it), and specify that you're looking for more recent recent information / experiences. If that still doesn't allow a more recent discussion on the topic to be held, maybe try elsewhere - reddit has various finance / personal finance forums, and there are likely other similar venues.